# Geth is not emitting pending transactons

Tags: go-ethereum, pending-transactions, bsc, websocket

I am connected to two nodes, mine and external. The external one emits pending transactions mine does not.

I started geth full node (after downloading a snapshot of the network). After 24h using eth.syncing I see.

```
{

currentBlock: 8024425,

highestBlock: 8024537,

knownStates: 102117366,

pulledStates: 102026296,

startingBlock: 1698957

}
```

Run command:

```
./geth --config ./config.toml --datadir /root/node --cache 18000 --rpc.allow-unprotected-txs --txlookuplimit 0 --ws
```

Can this be a synchronisation issue? Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, until the node has completed the synchronization it will not be able to validate transactions.

Answer (score 0):

The command `eth.syncing` should return `false`. If you see anything else, you are still syncing.